# Re-order records in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a an entity set like

```
public class StateInformation
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public bool ?locked { get; set; }
    public bool ?hidden { get; set; }
}
```

In some situation **hidden** field has the value **true** like

```
{
"columns": [
    {
        "id": "prescribingClNDC"
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribingClNDCDes",
        "locked": false
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribindClGenericName",
        "hidden": true,
        "locked": false
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribingClTheraputic",
        "locked": false,
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribingClTotalCost",
        "locked": false,
        "width": 100,
        "hidden": true
    }
]
```

}

This case i need to reorder all the records. That is, if a record have hidden field value 'true' will place at the end of the record set like

```
{
"columns": [
    {
        "id": "prescribingClNDC"
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribingClNDCDes",
        "locked": false
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribingClTheraputic",
        "locked": false,
        "width": 100
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribingClTotalCost",
        "locked": false,
        "width": 100,
        "hidden": true
    },
    {
        "id": "prescribindClGenericName",
        "hidden": true,
        "locked": false
    }
]
```

}

Is there any direct methode available in linq to handle this..?

Thanks
Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
var info = new List<StateInformation>() {
    new StateInformation() { id="1", locked = false, hidden = true },
    new StateInformation() { id="2", locked = false, hidden = false },
    new StateInformation() { id="3", locked = false}
};

var results = info.OrderBy(x => x.hidden.HasValue && x.hidden.Value).ToList();
```

the output will be:

```
2 False null 
3 False False 
1 False True
```